# R: adjusting line thickness in plot

Tags: r, graph, plot

```
prob_fun = function(n)
{
  dat = c(1 - phyper(14, (0.01*9999999999), 9999999999-0.01*9999999999, n),
                 1 - phyper(14, (0.02*9999999999), 9999999999-0.02*9999999999, n),
                 1 - phyper(14, (0.03*9999999999), 9999999999-0.03*9999999999, n),
                 1 - phyper(14, (0.04*9999999999), 9999999999-0.04*9999999999, n),
                 1 - phyper(14, (0.05*9999999999), 9999999999-0.05*9999999999, n))
  dat
}

data = sapply(1:2000, prob_fun)
plot(data[1,], ylim = c(0, 1))
lines(data[2,], lwd = 3)
```

I plotted `data[1,]`, but why does the line appear to be so much thicker than it should be (since the default `lwd` should `= 1`?). I plotted `data[2,]` with `lwd = 3` for comparison and it looks just fine. But why does the first line appear so much thicker? How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plotting a bazillion (OK, only 2000) consecutive values with points, so the "thick line" is really just a bunch of overlapping points.  Try

```
plot(data[1,], ylim = c(0, 1), type="l")
```

(`"l"` is for "lines"; you can use `lty=...`, `col=...` or something in addition to `lwd=...` to distinguish the two lines)

Here's a cleaner reformulation of your code:

```
prob_fun <- function(n,s=9999999999) {
   v <- (1:5)/100
   phyper(14, v*s, (1-v)*s, n, lower.tail=FALSE)
}
data <- t(sapply(1:2000, prob_fun))
matplot(data,type="l",lty=1)
```